# How to map a drive in a SQL Server script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I am trying to execute below script to Network a Drive

```
use master
go
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
go
reconfigure
go
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1;
go
reconfigure
go

EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use Z: \\RemoteServerName\SharedName'
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'Dir Z:'
```

Is there any script that  I can use to connect the network drive in long term

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can use UNC paths without resorting to `xp_cmdshell` and `net use`.

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you could use `\\\server\share\Whatever` without needing to map a drive at all (so UNC path only) but the security context running the T-SQL will need appropriate permissions to the SHARE and the NTFS of the full path to ensure it can do whatever commands you are running.

You could use `PUSHD` and `POPD` as:

```
PUSHD 
\\server\share 
Command \subfolder1\*.txt 
POPD
```

You could also use:

```
IF NOT EXIST Z: NET USE Z: \\server\share
command z:\folder\files.txt
```

Or perhaps something like the below with plugging in your variables:

```
DECLARE @folder AS VARCHAR(1000) = '\\server\share\folder1\folder2\finalfolder\'

DECLARE @command VARCHAR(500) = 'DIR /B "' + @folder + '*.xml"'
DECLARE @file VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @filesinafolder TABLE (filenameswithfolder VARCHAR(500))
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

-- create global temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##globalname') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##globalname

CREATE TABLE ##globalname (
StepResultID VARCHAR(50)
,StartTime VARCHAR(50)
,StopTime VARCHAR(50)
,ReturnCode INT
)

INSERT INTO @filesinafolder
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command
```